# Notation interpretation

Tags: soft-question, notation, relations

Consider the set $$\Bbb R^n :=\{x=(x_1,...,x_n):x_1,...,x_n \in \Bbb R \}.$$

For $x,y\in \Bbb R^n$, we define $<$ as below:  $$ x<y \iff  \exists j \in \{1,..,n \}  \left( x_j<y_j
\wedge \forall i  \in \Bbb N (i<j \to x_i=y_i)\right).$$

***The question is:***

if $j=n$,

follows $(x_1=y_1),...,(x_{n-1}=y_{n-1})$,
or do they differ?

Comment: I'm very confused what you're trying to ask.  $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}, i<j\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ is also ambiguous (how is $i<j$ in a set?  Do you mean $j\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$?)

Comment: @Hayden I'm going to add all the details

Comment: I just eddited and claryfied all. Hope, it works. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Now it is definitely written like I wanted to ask!

Answer (score 1):

The ordering you describe is the *lexicographic ordering*, the one that allows you to say that "car" will appear before "cat" in a dictionary. In this example, $j=3$ (i.e. the words differ only at their last letter, which is the third), and you are right, this means that the $n-1$ previous letters are the same.

Comment: Lets take "car" and "pet" follows $j=3, x_3<y_3$ and  the others differ, but still there is a lexicigraphical order. Or not?

Comment: @CAFosta: In this case $j=3$ does not work, since we have $x_1<y_1$. We have "car" < "pet", taking $j=1$ here.